# Why does this work? (Binding in a Panorama-Template, Windows Phone 7)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7, binding

The following code does work, but I don't understand exactly why. I just got to that solution by fluke.

```
<controls:Panorama x:Name="PanoramaMama" Title="my header">
    <controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
    <controls:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>

    <!--Panorama item one-->
    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item one">

        <Grid/>
    </controls:PanoramaItem>

    <!--Panorama item two-->
    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item two">
        <Grid/>
    </controls:PanoramaItem>
</controls:Panorama>
```

What I wanted to achieve was to create one HeaderTemplate for all PanoramaItems and specify the header-text in each PanoramaItem. e.g.: `<controls:PanoramaItem Header="item one">`

In the template, the binding without any parameters does the job: `Text="{Binding}"`

Why is this working?
The binding must use some default values (default Path or so) - which are those default values? What would the non abbreviated version of the binding be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've assigned a string as the object to use for the `Header` content.

You've also specified a `DataTemplate` to present the object assigned to the `Header` property. In this case as stated above that object is simply a string.  This string therefore becomes the `DataContext` of the `ContentPresenter` ultimately used to present the header.

When you use {Binding} without any Path the binding will return the source object.  Without specifying any source object the default source object is the current `DataContext` for the element on which the binding is set.  Therefore the result of {Binding} in this case is the string you assigned to the `Header` property.

There is no "non abbreviated version" for this binding, certainly not one that makes any sense.